# Calling a web service gives "Unable to connect to remote server error"

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am calling a web service from `.net` development environment located on my company's server. Everything was working fine until yesterday and it was returning correct data. However, today it suddenly gives me an error ***"Unable to connect to remote server"***. I entered the service URL in the browser, and that works fine. Does anybody have any idea what this problem could be about?

Comment: How does it feel to have posted the 3,000,000th question on SO?

Comment: Congratulations on the 3M post!!!

Comment: @ThePower I've just posted 33 questions so far!

Comment: @neuDev33 ThePower meant that your 33-rd question became Stack Overflow's 3000000's.[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130538/stack-overflow-hits-3-000-000-is-this-cool-or-what) is the link.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Oh I see, didnt know that! Yayy i guess!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing that comes to my mind is that the proxy configuration is now different between your application and your browser. Alternatively, it could be an antivirus program running on your machine that had its configuration updated.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestion on how to get around it?

Comment: If you don't have permissions to change things, then most likely there's nothing you can do without your admin's help. At least try to confirm what the problem is. If there's an antivirus (or firewall) then check its log (usually accessible) for your activity and your browser activity; good to compare. Check your browser's proxy information; and ultimately engage someone in the networking department to help you understand what changed overnight.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the webservice from app reference and re add.. it will work again.the error happens just because port number of webservice changed.